# Trying to use replace method with pandas

Tags: python, replace, pandas

I am trying to do a simple replace with pandas:

```
from pandas import *
In [2]: df = DataFrame({1: [2,3,4], 2: [3,4,5]})

In [4]: df[2]
Out[4]:
0    3
1    4
2    5
Name: 2

In [5]: df[2].replace(4, 17)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
c:\Python27\<ipython-input-5-b4adce9e9b15> in <module>()
----> 1 df[2].replace(4, 17)

AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'replace'
```

What am I missing?

Comment: This works fine for me with `pandas.version.version` 0.10.1, what version are you using?

Comment: I have no idea what the panda library is, but replacing methods with pandas sounds like a great idea to me.

Answer (score 3):

The [`replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.replace.html) method was added in version 0.9.0 (see [release notes](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.9.0/whatsnew.html#other-new-features)).

*Note: You can inspect the docs for a **specific version** of pandas by selecting that version on the [right-hand-side of the webpage](http://pandas.pydata.org/). But do consider updating to the latest stable version.*

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. Old version of pandas. Upgraded to newest version and problem solved.